# How To Achieve This Liquid Particle Effect

Tags: particles, effects

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-EIVlHvHRM&t=534s) video at minute 7:13 and also in the thumbnail there's this liquid particle effect i would love to recreate. I know that in the video it is somehow created with AI date, but I was wondering if there was a way to recreate this in Blender.

Comment: Some search about "vector displacement" should be a good starting point